# Linkedin Business verification issue to get LeadSync APis

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am trying to build an application which is connected with linkedin APis. In order to implement required functionaliy we need access to linkedin leadSync apis. We have requested saveral times to linkedin using developer account have provided them everything.

They get back to us with the same rejection that failed for business verification. I don't find any support or anything there, Is there any specific way to verify your business on linkedin in order to get access to linkedin development products?

We have tried to connect with support and everywhere but no response from anywhere. If anybody here is familiar with that, it would be really great. We have everything to submit but what exactly to submit and where to submit because in their development forum, they keep giving same answer.

Thanks in advance for anybody who helps.

#linkedin #linkedin_support